# Using typed constant as array size in C++ header

Tags: c++

I have a header file that declares constants as follows:

```
// foo.h
const unsigned FOO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8;
const unsigned FOO_NUM_BUFFERS = 4;

class FooSource {
    ...
    char buffer[FOO_BUFFER_SIZE];
    ...
};

class FooSink {
    ...
    void ProcessBuffer(char *buffer);
    ...
};
```

Unfortunately, this sometimes creates an unused variable warning in compilation units that don't use `FOO_NUM_BUFFERS`. The accepted method to avoid the warning is as follows:

```
// foo.h
extern const unsigned FOO_BUFFER_SIZE;
extern const unsigned FOO_NUM_BUFFERS;
...

// foo.cc
const unsigned FOO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8;
const unsigned FOO_NUM_BUFFERS = 4;
```

But this causes an `array bound is not an integer constant` warning for `FOO_BUFFER_SIZE`. I could use different styles for the two constants, but I'd prefer a consistent style.

Using `#define` would work, but would lose the benefits of typed constants. Moving the constants into one of the classes would also work, but it's not clear which class should "own" the constants as they are used by both.

Is there any better way to define these constants?

#### EDIT: the warning only occurs in strange circumstances - normally the const-style is OK

Specifically, the warning occurs when there is an unrelated compile error in the file, and the constant is initialized with the value of an inline function:

```
static inline unsigned f(unsigned x) {
    return x;
}

const unsigned FOO_CONSTANT = f(4);

class Foo {
    Foo() { create_a_compile_error; };
};
```

Gives the following compiler output with `g++ -Wall`:

```
In file included from foo.cc:2:0:
foo.h: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo()’:
foo.h:10:13: error: ‘create_a_compile_error’ was not declared in this scope
     Foo() { create_a_compile_error; };
             ^
foo.h: At global scope:
foo.h:7:16: warning: ‘FOO_CONSTANT’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 const unsigned FOO_CONSTANT = f(4);
                ^
```

Since I can't easily change the inline function to something more sensible, I think suppressing the warning is the right approach in this case.

Comment: If the constant is used in the only class, you can add it as a static constant in this class.

Comment: I do not know whether it's the thing you exactly want, however, you may also use enums to define such a constant.

Comment: "this sometimes creates an unused variable warning in compilation units that don't use the constant." Why? Isn't it declared in `foo.h` with the class `FooSource` which uses the const?

Comment: Either make it `static` or `constexpr` if you have C++11 compiler.

Comment: I was wondering why I don't get this and it seems `GCC` doesn't warn about *global consts* only local ones.

Comment: *" this sometimes creates an unused variable warning in compilation units that don't use the constant"* - How can the variable be "unused" if it is used for the array size? Please post a piece of code which reproduces the warning, and more information about your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I simplified it too much. I'm actually currently unable to reproduce the warning in a minimal example - indeed it seems the warning is only printed when another error is present in the file - so I suspect something else might be going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the best option would be to move the variable into a more fine-grained header, perhaps `FooBuffer.hpp`.

If this is not feasible, you can suppress the warning on a single variable using `__attribute__((unused))` (gcc and clang):

```
const unsigned FOO_BUFFER_SIZE __attribute__((unused)) = 8;
```

If Boost is available you can use [`BOOST_ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) (since 1.57).

As with any warning suppression you should document why the warning is being suppressed so that you can remove the suppression (and possibly the variable) if those conditions change.

Comment: And from C++17 the [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) `[[maybe_unused]]` is also available. The latest versions of GCC and Clang should already have it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use compiler-specific extensions like `__attribute__((unused))`.

Simply add a `typedef` to the header.

```
const unsigned FOO_NUM_BUFFERS = 4;
typedef char FOO_buffer[FOO_NUM_BUFFERS];
```

Compilers rarely warn about unused type definitions since that would cause numerous warnings when using standard headers (and that would be extremely unpopular with developers).   But, with most compilers, this does cause the compiler to recognise `FOO_NUM_BUFFERS` as being used.